# JQuery slideTo after slideToogle has completed

Tags: jquery, slidetoggle, scrollto

i have this jquery code which successfully uses `slideToggle` to open and close a div below.

```
$('#map-wrap').slideUp("fast");
$('#get-here-btn').click(function() {
    if (!$("#map-wrap").is(":visible"))
    $('#get-here-btn').addClass("active").html('Close');

    $("#map-wrap").slideToggle("fast","linear",function() { 
    if (!$("#map-wrap").is(":visible"))
        $('#get-here-btn').removeClass("active").html('How to get here');
       });       
});
```

i'd like to `scrollTo` the now-open div once it's open (with some sort of easing). i've tried a few variations and i can only get it to jump to the location (is this because the element is hidden when the button is clicked?) rather than slide.

i know i should probably add the scrollTo into the slideToggle function but am not sure where?

any help much appreciated.
thanks in advance, Leon

i've knocked up a JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/leonharris/rZqwx

Answer (score 1):

Taken from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6677035/jquery-scroll-to-element) question:

Assuming you have a button with the id 'button', try this example:

```
$("#button").click(function() {
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $("#elementtoScrollToID").offset().top
    }, 2000);
});
```

Obviously you'd have to adapt it to your case.

Comment: so if i needed to add in the slideToggle before the animate would i do it like this:
button.click > slideToggle > animate?`
eg: $("#button").click(function() {
    $("#elementtoScrollToID").slideToggle( function() { 
        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: $("#elementtoScrollToID").offset().top
        }, 2000);
     });
});

Comment: @Leon Yes, pretty much. But since the slide itself already takes a short amount of time, I'd say you could trigger both animations simultaneously. But it's up to you.